# is there a way to highlight sql queries in php files in Brackets.io?

Tags: php, adobe-brackets

I write PHP code in Brackets, but SQL queries are not highlighted as SQL language, the whole text is in one color. Is there a theme or a different way to highlight queries as SQL language. This works well in Atom, but I would like to work in Brackets.

Comment: Can you paste your code please?

Answer (score 1):

http://brackets.dnbard.com/extension/brackets-php-syntax-hint

"PHP Syntax Hint is a plugin for Brackets, which will help you alot in writing php SYNTAX, MYSQL Queries as this will auto suggest Syntax while coding, within Brackets software."

Seems to be what you wanted.

Comment: No, I am looking for a way to change color highlighting. For example, i have this code `$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username='$login'");`. In Brackets everything betwing "" is in one color, but in Atom SELECT, FROM, WHERE are in different color according to SQL color highlighting. I want to have the same in Brackets.